# Distributional PDE solutions as topological linear duals of PDE solutions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, lorentzian-geometry

Let

$$
  P \;\colon\; \Gamma_\Sigma(E) \to \Gamma_\Sigma(\tilde E^\ast)
$$

be a formally self-adjoint hyperbolic linear differential operator ($\tilde E^\ast$ denotes the densitized dual of a smooth vector bundle $E$) which has unique advanced and retarded Green functions $\mathrm{G}_{\pm}$. Then by prop. 2.1 in

- Igor Khavkine, "Covariant phase space, constraints, gauge and the
  Peierls formula", Int. J. Mod. Phys. A, 29, 1430009 (2014)
  ([arXiv:1402.1282](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1282))

there is an exact sequence of vector spaces of smooth sections the form

$$
  0 
    \to  
  \Gamma_{\Sigma,cp}(E)
   \overset{P}{\longrightarrow}
  \Gamma_{\Sigma,cp}(\tilde E^\ast)
    \overset{\mathrm{G}}{\longrightarrow}
  \Gamma_{\Sigma,scp}(E)
    \overset{P}{\longrightarrow}
  \Gamma_{\Sigma,scp}(\tilde E^\ast)
     \to
  0
  \,,
$$

where $\mathrm{G} := \mathrm{G}_+ - \mathrm{G}_-$ is the causal Green function, where "cp" means compact support and "scp" means spacelike compact support.

This implies in particular that linear functionals on the space $ker_{scp}(P)$ of solutions are equivalently those linear functionals on all compactly supported sections which are "distributional weak solutions" in that they vanish on the image of $P$:

$$
  \left(
    ker_{scp}(P)
  \right)^\ast
    \underset{\simeq}{\overset{(-)\circ \mathrm{G}}{\longrightarrow}}
  \left(
    \Gamma_{\Sigma,cp}(\tilde E^\ast)/im(P)
  \right)^\ast
$$

**Question:** With the usual topologies from distribition theory, is the analogous map of linear *topological* duals of *topological* vector spaces still an isomorphism?

Comment: Igor Khavkine has kindly provided the proof here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Green+hyperbolic+partial+differential+equation#ContinousLinearFunctionalsOnTheSolutionSpace

Comment: Why not make this an answer?